# How to fix my Facebook Login issue with ominauth and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth-facebook

Im trying to make my facebook login works with my application. This is my setup on facebook developer:

[image]

My applications is running correctly on my heroku server.

When I try to sign with Facebook I get this message:

```
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

What Im missing here?

Thanks

Comment: For confirmation, the first URL in your screenshot is your Heroku app? The c9users is an AWS/cloud9 instance but it's not clear that the other is Heroku

Comment: Don’t see that message when using the Facebook login on that site, it shows the login dialog fine. Do you get this as an API response afterwards, when the user has been redirected back to your app? Then the problem is likely in the step that tries to exchange the code for a token - the `redirect_uri` parameter in that API call must have the exact same value that was used in the login dialog call.